# Find Percentage Contribution in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

[image]

I want to find the percentage of product sold from the percentage of product a customer was given to sell.

From the above table, Customers(CustID) have some products for sale, and the percentage product they were given. For example, Customer 1 has 32 product of which his total across the CustID is 15%. From table B, he sold 12 out of 32 product of which was 15%

Now, the logic is to find in percentage the product sold. That is, "What percentage did 12 contribute to 15% of the 32 product he had?
Thank you

Comment: I would do this in the SQL.   You might be able to do it in SSRS with the LOOKUP function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the percentage of the product sold as compared to the product he was given, and then multiply that by the percentage of the total product he was given.

Example for Customer 1:

12 is 37.5% of 32

37.5% of 15% is 5.6%

```
=(Fields!ProductSold.Value / Fields!Product.Value) * (Fields!Product.Value / Sum(Fields!Product.Value)
```

That being said, it would be easier just to get the percent of what he sold compared to the total given.

```
=Sum(Fields!Product.Value) / Fields!ProductSold.Value
```

Hope this helps.